C# MAUI элемент slider работает не стабильно
Запускаю программу на эмуляторе: Android Pixel 3A API 30. При нажатии кнопки видны изменения на странице, а при изменении положения slider их нет. Однако, если после запуска программы удалить кусок кода slider из MainPage.xaml и вернуть обратно, то все работает так как и задумывалось.
XAML:
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">

            <!--Вот этот кусок удалить и вставить обратно-->
            <Slider 
                x:Name="mySlider" 
                ValueChanged="slider_valueChanged" 
                Minimum="30"
                Maximum="100"/>


            <Label
                x:Name="myLabel"
                Text="something"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"/>

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="start"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

Код страницы:
namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myLabel.Text = "change text";
        }

        private void slider_valueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            myLabel.Text = arg.Value;
        }
    }
}


Нашел решение - нужно задать значение Value при инициализации:
<Slider 
    x:Name="timeSlider"
<--Добавить строчку ниже-->
    Value="30"
    ValueChanged="slider_valueChanged" 
    Minimum="30"
    Maximum="100"/>

